# Matlab dimension error

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I was writing a code that would draw an edge of an image (2448 x 3264) by calculating the standard deviation of nearby pixels forming a 3 by 3 square.

```
clear ; close all; clc;

Image = imread ('image.JPG');

k = 1;

n = size(Image,1);
m = size(Image,2);

Ex = zeros(n+2,m+2);

E = zeros(2248,3264,3);

for k = 1:3;

    Ex([2:n+1],[2:m+1],k) = Image([1:n],[1:m],k);

    for x = 2:n+1;
        for y = 2:m+1;
            Idx = Image([x-1:x+1],[y-1:y+1],k);

            IDx = Idx';
            IDx = IDx(:);

            idx = find(IDx ~= 0);
            IDx = IDx(idx);
            num = length(IDx);

            M = sum(IDx)/num;
            E(x-1,y-1,k) = sqrt(sum(Idx.^2)/num - M^2);

            percent_x = x/n * 100
        end
    end
end
imshow(E)
```

After I ran the code above, matlab gave me an error:

Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

How do I fix this?
It worked without the for k = 1:3 loop, and calculating only k = 1.

Comment: You have no `k` in your code....

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and the *full* error and stack trace.

Comment: This is just a simple programming mistake (and I got the error even when k=1).  In Matlab, sum only sums along one dimension, so the result on line 30 is a 1x3 vector rather than a single value as you expected.  It is quickly fixed with `E(x-1,y-1,k) = sqrt(sum(sum(Idx.^2))/num - M^2);`.  However, there are other bugs in the code.  I think lines 18 and 19 should be `for x=2:n-1` and `for y=2:m-1` otherwise you exceed the image bounds on the following line.  (Not to mention that the result is complex as the argument to sqrt is not guaranteed to be positive).